# Solve $y' = (1+\frac{y-1}{2x})^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $y' = (1+\frac{y-1}{2x})^2$

My first thought was to expand to see if I can get a linear form:

$$y' = 1 + \frac{y-1}{x} + (\frac{y-1}{2x})^2 = 1 + \frac{y-1}{x} + \frac{y^2-2y+1}{4x^2}$$

$$y'  = 1 + \frac{y}{x} -\frac{1}{x} + \frac{y^2}{4x^2} +  \frac{-2y}{4x^2} +  \frac{1}{4x^2} \rightarrow y'+y(\frac{2}{4x^2}-\frac{1}{x}) = \frac{(2x-1)^2+y^2}{4x^2}$$

However, this is not even a bernoulli equation. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If you consider $$u=1+\dfrac{y-1}{2x}$$ then we get $$y'=2xu'+2u-2.$$ Thus the original equation becomes

$$2xu'+2u-2=u^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would try is $v = y - 1$

$$
v' = \left(1+\frac{v}{2x}\right)^2
$$
Let $v = wx$

$$
w + xw' = \left(1+\frac{w}{2}\right)^2
$$
which is basically
$$
xw' = g(w)
$$
now see if you can solve this ODE.

Comment: I didn't understand how you moved from second equation to $xw'=g(w)$

Comment: @JitendraSingh Expanding the RHS, there is a term $+ w$ to match the one on the LHS so they cancel, giving $$x w' = 1 + w^{2}/4 = g(w)$$

Comment: @JitendraSingh I just hid all the $w$ terms on the LHS but should be solvable from there as mattos pointed out :).

Comment: now understood thanks @mattos and Chinny84

Answer (score 0):

$$y' = \left(1+\frac{y-1}{2x}\right)^2$$
Substitute :
$$z=1+\frac{y-1}{2x}$$
$$y'=2(z-1+xz')$$
Then  the DE is separable.
$$2xz'=(z-1)^2+1$$